# Proper integration of Admob Banner ads in JetPack Compose

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for correct integration of Admob Banner ads in my JetPack Compose View.
In my case, I used to load Banner Ads in LazyColumn between various LazyColumn Items. But I am having a problem with combination of LazyColumn and Banner Ad. The banner Ad loads perfectly initially, but once I scroll away from my Ad view and the banner Ad becomes hidden, and then when I scroll back to my banner ad view, the ad view starts to reload again and the previously loaded ad gets killed.

Can anyone please guide me how do I prevent the Banner Ad View to get killed when I scroll away without causing it to reload again and again

The code that I am using is -

```
//MainView where I load ad 
@Composable
fun MainView(){
  
 LazyColumn{
   
   //other contents
   item {
    BannerAdView()
   }
   //other contents
  }
}


//BannerAdView
@Composable
fun BannerAdView() {

 AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        factory = { context ->
            AdView(context).apply {
                setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
                adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.adId)
                loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                adListener = object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded() {
                        isAdLoaded = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
 }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I faced the same issue.  :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, `areAdsDisabled()` will return true or false depending upon your usecase

```
@Composable
fun BannerAdView(adUnitId: String) {
    if (!areAdsDisabled()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            factory = { context ->
                val adView = AdManagerAdView(context)
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
                adView
            },
            update = { adView ->
                adView.adUnitId = adUnitId
                adView.doOnLayout {
                    adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @mayur can you marked this as solved if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use ViewModel

```
class AdViewModel : ViewModel() {
var adView: AdView? by mutableStateOf(null)
```

}

Banner Function

```
fun AdaptiveBannerAdView(adViewModel: AdViewModel) {
val adView = adViewModel.adView
val currentScreenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
if (adView == null) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val newAdView = AdView(context).apply {
        setAdSize(AdSize.getPortraitInlineAdaptiveBannerAdSize(context, currentScreenWidth))
        adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"

        loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                // Ad loaded, you can perform any additional actions here
            }
        }
    }

    // Store the AdView in the ViewModel
    adViewModel.adView = newAdView

    // Load the ad when this Composable is first composed

}

// Check if adView is non-null before using it in AndroidView
if (adView != null) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        factory = { adView }
    )
}
```

}